# How to check if 2D array has 3 same values in a row

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I’m just wondering how is it possible to check if in my 2D array are 3 same values in a row .

I’ve tried to search it here, or on Google but nothing really helped me . Only thing closest to my goal is this.

```
function check(array, length) {
var count = 0,
    value = array[0];

return array.some(function (a) {
    if (value !== a) {
        count = 0;
        value = a;
    }
    return ++count === length;
});
}

console.log('length: 3');
console.log(check(["g", "z", "z", "z"], 3));                // true
console.log(check(["g", "z", "z", "v" ,"b", "b", "b"], 3)); // true
console.log(check(["z", "g", "z", "z"], 3));                // false
```

But It doesn’t work for 2D arrays like this. And I can’t really figure it out how to make this work.

```
Let arr=[
 [" ", " "," "],
 [" ", " "," "],
 [" ", " "," "],
]
```

Keep in mind this 2D array will be generated at the start of the app by user. It can be any length. For example 6x6 , 3x3 ,etc

So there needs to be approach which will loop thru all of the rows and cols.

I’ve tried to do it like this, it partly works. Problem is that, it counts not only 3 in a row but 3 totally in the row.

```
Let count = 0;
Let searchedValue = "x";
Let ThreeSame=false;

For(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
   For(let j=0;j<arr[i]+length;i++){
      If(arr[i][j] === searchedValue){
        count++
      }
      If(count === 3){
        Return ThreeSame=true;
      }
   }
}
```

The Best way will be if it checks horizontally, vertically and diagonally.

Thanks.

Comment: `Let array=[
 [‘’,` will result in a few SyntaxErrors, as will `Let ThreeSame=false;

For(let i=0;` and the rest of that code block

Comment: Sorry for that,I’ve written it all on mobile . So thats because of ticks. Should be OK now

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function that will do this. Be sure to send array only when you know it is generated properly and has at least one row and column.

```js
const check = (array, length) => {
    let value = array[0][0]
    let count = 0
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length && count !== length; i++){
      for(let j = 0; j < array[i].length && count !== length; j++){
        if(value.trim().length > 0 && array[i][j] === value){
          count++
        }
        else{
          value = array[i][j]
          count = 1
        }
      }
    }
    return count === length
}
```

Basically, you are looping through the matrix and checking for the value. If the current element is not equal to the value, you must set the value you are looking for to the current element, and set counter to 1, to count in the current element which is already set or "found".

You do not need a third variable. To optimize the solution, add checks to see if you reached the length needed to both for loops and at the end just return if the count matches the length.

Also, generally not a good practice to return from inside a loop, as it can be hard to track down what's happening in the code in future. Always try to use additional loop conditions and only return at the end of the function.

Comment: Not working for me.. Tried to send array like this to it

  let arr=[
    [" "," ","x","x"],
    ["x","x"," "," "],
    [" "," "," "," "]
  ]

and returned true. expected result was false

Comment: Ok, I got your point. I edited the code snippet so now it will not look at " " (empty string) as an actual element. But still, the array you posted does return true, as there are 4 x's in a row (2 at the end of first row, 2 at the start of second row). Do you want to check when there are EXACTLY 3 x's in a row and no more?